# How to add some object to sendMessage or add this object to Extra in telegraf.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf

I have telegram bot using a telegraf.js library. I have some users that have been registered in bot, and I want to send a confirmation of something consent from one user to another. For realizing it, I need to add in *sendMessage* some *consentId*, but I don`t know how!

(this is pseudo-code, here I show my imagination of how that can be work)

```
bot.action('createContract', ctx => {
    // we have some consent object from sequlize with right id
    const consent = {
        id          : uuid4(),
        status      : 'PENDING',
        initiatorId : uuid4(),
        consonantId : uuid4()
    };

    sequelize.model.User.findByPk(consent.consonantId).then(user => {
        // here i need add consentId to sendMessage but not show it to user
        ctx.telegram.sendMessage(
            user.chatId,
            'Do you confirm ....',
            Extra.HTML().markup((m) =>
                m.inlineKeyboard([
                    m.callbackButton('sign', 'sign'),
                    m.callbackButton('decline', 'decline')
                ]))
        );
    });
});


bot.action('sign', ctx => {
    // here we must a get consentId that we add in createContract action
    sequelize.model.Consent.findByPk(ctx.consentId).then(consent => {
        return consent.update({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
    });
});
```

Comment: what can not you do?

Comment: I don`t know how to add some params to sendMessage(or something other function ) and return this param in action event.

Comment: still need solution?